# preserving JSON in jq with massive filter and sub()

Tags: jq

So i have this massive jq filter, and i can pretty much get it to do what i want.

```
cat test.json |jq '.spec.install.spec.deployments[].spec.template.spec.containers[].env[] | select(.name | contains("_IMAGE")) | .value |= sub("registry.redhat.io"; "repo.home.nicknach.net:5000"; "g")'
```

which yields:

```
{
  "name": "ELASTICSEARCH_IMAGE",
  "value": "repo.home.nicknach.net:5000/openshift4/ose-logging-elasticsearch5@sha256:ea785fcfd3896d22a96eaea2dc5aab6496c2b8f79005d3e8a49b8b69320ed877"
}
{
  "name": "FLUENTD_IMAGE",
  "value": "repo.home.nicknach.net:5000/openshift4/ose-logging-fluentd@sha256:41718848dff54ef399b05cb9ba93f1b498dc656ae625638fbfb277aab46de2c9"
}
{
  "name": "KIBANA_IMAGE",
  "value": "repo.home.nicknach.net:5000/openshift4/ose-logging-kibana5@sha256:ddf4a9ea97213775576a8c4d340ca6e7f1117dc5e97378adbc01cda4f1eabb26"
}
...
```

The problem is, i dont understand how to get the entire JSON (it's huge) with my modified values.  Is this possible in jq?  I seem to only be able to get the parts that i modified.  I want the entire thing, with the parts that i modified in there.

Comment: See [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, and since you know about `|=` I would have thought you could figure it out for yourself.  Without further information, it's difficult to give specifics -- see oguzismail's comment, with particular emphasis on `minimal`.

Answer (score 0):

[`|=` (Update-assignment)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Update-assignment:%7C=) operates on paths. `.spec.install.spec.deployments[].spec.template.spec.containers[].env[] | …` is a filter which already modifies your document.

TLDR: you are missing parentheses to turn the left-hand side of the assignment into a single path expression:

```
(
  .spec.install.spec.deployments[].spec.template.spec.containers[].env[]
  | select(.name | contains("_IMAGE"))
  | .value
) |= sub("registry.redhat.io"; "repo.home.nicknach.net:5000"; "g")
```

NB: always provide an [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make it easier for answerers to actually answer your question. I had to come up with a valid (?) input myself:

```json
{
    "spec": {
        "install": {
            "spec": {
                "deployments": [
                    {
                        "spec": {
                            "template": {
                                "spec": {
                                    "containers": [
                                        {
                                            "env": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "ES_IMAGE",
                                                    "value": "registry.redhat.io/yada"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "name": "KIBANA_IMAGE",
                                                    "value": "registry.redhat.io/yada"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "name": "other_var",
                                                    "value": "not a registry.redhat.io"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "env": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "ES_IMAGE",
                                                    "value": "registry.redhat.io/yada"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "name": "KIBANA_IMAGE",
                                                    "value": "registry.redhat.io/yada"
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which yields the following output when being applied the above filter:

```json
{
  "spec": {
    "install": {
      "spec": {
        "deployments": [
          {
            "spec": {
              "template": {
                "spec": {
                  "containers": [
                    {
                      "env": [
                        {
                          "name": "ES_IMAGE",
                          "value": "repo.home.nicknach.net:5000/yada"
                        },
                        {
                          "name": "KIBANA_IMAGE",
                          "value": "repo.home.nicknach.net:5000/yada"
                        },
                        {
                          "name": "other_var",
                          "value": "not a registry.redhat.io"
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "env": [
                        {
                          "name": "ES_IMAGE",
                          "value": "repo.home.nicknach.net:5000/yada"
                        },
                        {
                          "name": "KIBANA_IMAGE",
                          "value": "repo.home.nicknach.net:5000/yada"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```